# Final Form calculate set object to a position in array values

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I am setting up a parser for one of my fields, if user types 'Honda' for example, it will get matching DB values like: {make: 'Honda', id: 5, year: '2012'} and etc.
I would like to set field values when I get response from API.

Is it possible instead of the following

```
updates(value, name, allValues) => {
  return {
    ['vehicle[0].make']: 'Honda',
    ['vehicle[0].year']: '2012',
   ....
 }
}
```

to set values like following:

```
updates(value, name, allValues) => {
      return {
        ['vehicle[0]']: {
            make: 'Honda', 
            id: 5, 
            year: '2012'
       ....
     }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. It's not working? Got a sandbox to demonstrate it?

Comment: It didn't work, I went through another way.